# Command substitution, assignment, tests and spaces

Tags: bash, variable, test, command-substitution

I know the whole language is confusing, but I am having trouble understanding assignments with command substitutions:

```
x=Example sentence                  #1 fails due to space
x='Example sentence'                #2 ok 
echo $x                             #3 ok
[ -n $(echo $x) ]  && echo foo      #4 fails due to space
[ -n "$(echo $x)" ]  && echo foo    #5 ok
y=$x                                #6 ok
y=$(echo $x)                        #7 ok, not like 1?
[ -n $y ]                           #8 fails due to space
```

With practice, I have learned that command substitutions in tests should always be surrounded by quotes (e.g. `[ -n "$(cmd)" ]`), and that quotes can be used inside the substitution without interfering with outside quotes. Quoting a substitution seems to capture `stdout`, but not `stderr` (unless redirected).

**Q1.** But what happens when the substitution is *not* quoted (cases 4 and 7)?

Specifically, I am confused with the apparent difference in behaviour between assignments `x=$(cmd)`, which seem to work fine with spaces, versus tests `[ -n $(cmd) ]`, which seem to always be truthy.

**Q2.** Is it bad practice to assign command substitutions without quotes `x=$(cmd)`? Should I always quote them `x="$(cmd)"`?

Comment: This is very well explained at [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/112235)

Comment: @Inian Thanks for the link, and sorry for the redundant question. Please feel free to vote to close if you consider this to be a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/112235)

Comment: TL;DR Quotes generally prevent split+glob expansions. Variable assignment is a special case where quotes are not needed. Tests with double brackets `[[ ]]` is another special case, but single brackets `[ ]` require quotes.   ----   Q1: assignments are just special. Q2: it's fine not to quote.